# Using PyMuPDF fitz to Swap the Overall Font in a Document

Tags: python, pdf

I'm attempting to use fitz in a Python script to swap the font in a PDF document, and possibly change its size by an increment or ratio (in order to keep the elements to scale in respect to each other).

Also, I suck at Python.

Here's my attempt:

```
def change_font(input_pdf, output_pdf, new_font):
    try:
        pdf_document = fitz.open(input_pdf)

        for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
            # get page (I think this is where the error is coming from)
            page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)

            # get text from page
            text = page.get_page_text()

            # change font of entire page
            page.insert_text((0, 0), text, fontname=new_font)
            # (not sure how the (0, 0) position is going to work out...)

        # save
        pdf_document.save(output_pdf)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    # to keep original file safe
    finally:
        if 'pdf_document' in locals():
            pdf_document.close()

# Input parameters
input_pdf = input('Input file name: ')
output_pdf = input('New document name: ')
new_font = input('New font name: ')

change_font(input_pdf, output_pdf, new_font)
```

After a few hours of work, I'm still getting the following output, after having manually specified all three parameters:

`An error occurred: 'Document' object has no attribute 'load_page'`

I don't necessarily need someone to rewrite the whole thing. My real question is simply why this error is happening, as I've been trying to fix it for a while now. If I manage to fix that, I can continue developing the script by myself.

I'm running Python 3.9.2 on Debian Bookworm.

Comment: Regarding the error, use [camelCase](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/znames.html) (*i.e* `loadPage`) or update your fitz' version.

Comment: `doc.load_page(pno)` is correct as well as simply `doc[pno]`. If this does not work, your installation of PyMuPDF went wrong.

Comment: For the task itself have a look at [this](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/tree/master/font-replacement) set of scripts, which allows replacing one font by another.